# i am facing difficulty in setup process fleetcart template which is related to laravel framework

Tags: laravel-8

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMTbh.png)i have purchased a fleecart template which is in laravel framework ,so i had that code in a archive folder, initillay we need to set up it such that theme template will convert into actual  framework code, we had  a problem while set up it .  Help me with this.
If you see image below, if the mentioned steps if i eneterd correctly it must take me to the installation process, but it is throwing errors.